# How can I simplifly the below?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var r1a =  word
    .split(/[^a-z0-9\s.\|]/gi)
    .join("")
    .split(/([~@#$%^&*()_+=`{}\[\]\\:;<>\/ ])+/g)
    .join("");
```

I believe I am using join function twice which is unnecessary

How can I do the same thing above while doing the join only once?

Comment: What is the input and expected output?

Comment: What is the text you're trying to use? so what is in the `word` variable?

Comment: this is really a regex question, not a JavaScript question.

Comment: @Claies the language is important for regex questions because of differences in the engines.

Comment: @Mathletics true, but in this case, the question is predominantly about how to perform the regex in one pass instead of two, and the question didn't have a regex tag at all.

Answer (score 2):

`str.split(regex).join("")` can be simplified to `str.replace(regex, "")`.

Comment: As long as the regex has the global flag set. Otherwise, `replace()` will only replace the first match.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to what ipsec said, you should be able to combine the regexes and do a single `.replace()` call:

```
var word = "HESDF@#^#WEHWERJUWWHWSD654684s6dSDfW#T#SDFZ$W&&)@*#$";
var r1a =  word
    .split(/[^a-z0-9\s.\|]/gi)
    .join("")
    .split(/([~@#$%^&*()_+=`{}\[\]\\:;<>\/ ])+/g)
    .join("");

var blah = word.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s.\|]|([~@#$%^&*()_+=`{}\[\]\\:;<>\/ ])+/gi,'');

console.log(r1a === blah);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95yh6fbq/)

Comment: `[^a-z0-9\s.|]` matches already all the characters of the other character class, so the second part is not needed.

Comment: The dot is seen as a literal character in a character class, there is no need to escape it.